# Slack block kit clears inputs when user switches channels

Tags: slack, slack-api

I googled around but couldn't find any documentation on this.

But I created an form with slack block kit, and it works well but if a user selects an option and then navigates to a different channel and back it clears out the option.

Functionally it works fine because I only get the one POST request with the value that the user had input but its a bad UX because then the user can't see which form item they had previously selected. Is this expected?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may misunderstand how the interaction flow between Slack and your app is supposed to work.

Once the user selected the option and your app received the corresponding request, it is your app's responsibility to update the message on the Slack channel with the result of the user's choice (in case you want to give the user feedback on his choice, which I would recommend).

Comment: Wouldn't updating the message update it for everyone?

Comment: Depends on the type of the message, which has the select element. If it's public and not ephemeral, yes.

Comment: Yes its a public message, thats why using update isn't really an option. I do use ephemeral messages to confirm what the user has selected but its a little annoying that it clears when you change workspaces.